# Season 20 Holy Shotgun Paladin - Which stat to choose?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just got an Obsidian Ring of the Zodiac which upgrades my current one. It is a ancient semi perfect roll:

- +7% attack speed,
- 8% resource cost reduction,
- 6% Crit,
- only **6%** cool down reduction.

I would like to know which stat I should re-roll. I'm using Captain Crimson's Trimming bonus, so the cool down would increase my DMG DEALT and the cost reduction would increase my survivability.

As it is, it's grating +5% of raw dmg. I wouldn't like to give away my dmg reduction cause I'm a little squishy already, so second to that, which stat should I re-roll to get more dmg? In another words: Is 6% of "Damage dealt" bigger than 5% of "raw" damage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this ["Aegis of Valor Heaven's Fury Crusader" guide](https://www.icy-veins.com/d3/aegis-of-valor-heavens-fury-crusader-bis-gear-gems-paragon-points) best stats for your rings are:

> - Socket
> - Critical Hit Chance
> - Critical Hit Damage
> - Area Damage

And this is what this guide says about CDR:

> Heaven's Fury Crusaders are heavily Cooldown-dependent, so try to your best to reach a 60%+ CDR point in your sheet to ease the strain on your Obsidian Ring of the Zodiac resets.

If you have around 60% CDR already I suggest rolling CDR into Socket (this is the most important thing - Legendary Gem in this socket outweighs any single stat) or into second critical stat (if you already have Socket since you mentioned only 1 crit). If you are far from that CDR limit, I suggest rolling Attack Speed into Socket or crit - your build's goal is to deal damage with shield reflects anyway, so your own attack speed is less relevant.

As for your second question about damage difference - check [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/220566/144891).

Comment: tks for. the insight... looking at that guide, the writer said that 60% CDR is desired but hw only prioritises shoulder, weapon, shield and gauntlets. Those combine up to a max of 34% (10+8+8+8)... where the hell are we supposed to pull the remaining 26?!?!?

Comment: currently im using Gogok, and my base CDR is 50% and let me tell,  quite oftenly I see myself dangerously close to run of of Akarat while "frozen" from the stone gauntlets

Comment: @Leonardo you can get some CDR from Paragon levels, but I don't remember exact numbers